# Is a ThreadAbortException bad?

Tags: dxa, dxa-net

I noticed that if I request a not existing binary in my DXA webapp I get some funny errors in Visual Studio's Output window.

Requesting a non exiting item. `http://localhost:81/demo/Images/bogus_tcm58-544654.png` (there is no item 544654 in my CM)

Output window:

```
Exception thrown: 'Sdl.Web.Common.DxaItemNotFoundException' in Sdl.Web.Tridion.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Threading.ThreadAbortException' in mscorlib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Threading.ThreadAbortException' in System.Web.dll
```

The DxaItemNotFound exception is expected: the item really does not exist.
Should I be alarmed about the ThreadAbortException? I never really noticed it beofore and the request is handled as normal otherwise.

Running DXA 1.7 .NET, in Visual Studio 2015 with IIS Express.

Answer (score 6):

AFAIK, `ThreadAbortExceptions` are quite common in ASP.NET. For example, if you terminate the HTTP processing pipeline using `Response.End()` (something that for example the `StaticContentModule` does in places), this results in the processing thread being aborted.

Processing threads may also be aborted because of (idle) timeouts. So, in general, I wouldn't worry too much about these exceptions unless they are causing issues.